# run bundle install when creating new app in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im new to Ruby On Rails. I installed rails 3.1.2 on ubuntu 11.04. Every time i run `rails new <appname>` at the end it does `run bundle install`. 
This takes quite some time to complete. Is run bundle install needed everytime an app is created, and if not is there any way to prevent it from running everytime i create a new rails application,so that rails new completes quickly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `rails new <appname> --skip-bundle`.